# Jumping between forms in C# that are in random order

Tags: forms

Created a survey style application using forms, it contains 30 forms. For example, the first page asks the user to check which surveys to load, and according to their checks it opens up the correct form. Everything works correctly in one direction. The way I have the program set up is the first page saves static Boolean variables, The control class (Main method), checks if the variables are true or false then opens the corresponding forms. Like this;

```
if (Survey.r == true || Survey.s == true || SurveySelection.M == true )
            {
                Form6 newform6 = new Form6(); 
                Form6.Hide();
                Form6.ShowDialog();

                Form7 newform7 = new Form6(); 
                Form7.Hide();
                Form7.ShowDialog();          

             }
if (Survey.t == true)
            {
                Form12 newform12 = new Form12();
                newform12.Hide();
                newform12.ShowDialog();

            }
```

And So on in total 30 forms. The next button on each form just contains this.Hide(), on them.

The problem is if I were to add a back button on this Survey, 
I am not sure how to handle it, since the survey is not linear is more logical since it depends on the type of survey the user chooses.

It could load forms 4,19,24,26 in one instance and 3, 6, 9 in other. I need help or guidance implementing a back button to this logic. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thirty forms is not a lot. You could create a List and maintain a pointer to the current location.

```
private InitializeKnowSequence()
{
    _formIndex = 0;
    _formsList.Add(new Form2());
    _formsList.Add(new Form2());
    _formsList.Add(new Form3());
    _formsList.Add(new Form4());
}

private void NavigatePrior()
{
    if (_formIndex > 0)
    {
        _formsList[_formIndex--].Hide();
        _formsList[_formIndex].Show();
    }
}

private void NavigateNext()
{
    if(_formIndex<_formsList.Count()-1)
    {                
        _formsList[_formIndex++].Hide();
        _formsList[_formIndex].Show();
    }           
}
```

Then add a PushForm(Form form) method for logical branches forward

```
private void PushForm(Form form)
{
    _formsList.Add(form);
     NavigateNext();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to navigate forward/backward without any problem.